# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I am new to spring and hibernate .... I was trying to import and run a  project using maven from mykyong site ... the link is at https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/ 
i imported and tried to run the project but it showed the exception mentioned in the title .............. the exception is with the hibernate transaction ... which probably is not there .............. the database connection is properly done and required changes are done in the database.properties file

the source files can be looked into from the link provided .... Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of Spring if the above exception occurs when you don't create **beans** in  your DataSource.xml. Check your db url, it would be like 192.160...if you are using local machine.